# Create a password to access a program

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program that requires a login access to get 100% access to the rest of the program for work. But I couldn't create it, I searched on internet but doesn't work for me.

Here is my code:

```
from getpass import getpass

password = getpass("Please enter your key:")

if password == "1234":
    print("Successful Login!")
else:
    print("Incorrect Login, Try it again.")
```

The problem is that whether you put the correct or incorrect password, program will log in anyway. I want that if you put the wrong password you can't get access to the tools of the program.

Comment: What you've shown will tell the user the password is incorrect if it isn't 1234, so it's unclear what your problem is.

Comment: Your program works for me, as well. So what's your problem?!

Comment: I'm guessing you're not using a loop.

Answer (score 3):

sys is really useful for this type of stuff.

If you get the wrong password it'll exit the program early.

```
from getpass import getpass
import sys

password = getpass("Please enter your key:")

if password == "1234":
    print("Successful Login!")
else:
    print("Incorrect Login.")
    sys.exit(1)


print("Rest of program")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code is of the format:

```
from getpass import getpass

#password check
password = getpass("Please enter your key:")

if password == "1234":
    print("Successful Login!")
else:
    print("Incorrect Login, Try it again.")

#program code here...
```

The issue is that after the `else` block, the program will continue execution normally and will reach the code below the `else` block. Two ways to prevent this are:

### 1- Terminate the program with `exit()`

In the else block, you can terminate the program on password failure:

```
import sys

#......
if password == "1234":
    print("Successful Login!")
else:
    print("Incorrect Login, Try it again.")
    sys.exit(1) #exit with status code 1
```

---

### 2- Loop until the password is correct

A slightly more user-friendly approach is to keep prompting the user for the password until they enter the right one. Like so, users do not have to re-run a program if they made a typo.

```
password = getpass("Please enter your key:")
while password != "1234":
    print("Incorrect Login, Try it again.")
    password = getpass("Please enter your key:")

print("Successful login!") #success
#proceed with rest of program...
```

Comment: I think `exit()` has an exit code of 0 by default, suggesting a successful outcome. I think takes an argument which could rectify this

Comment: Well, this still terminates the program, regardless of the exit code.

Comment: @CameronDowner Alright, if user wants to exit with a status code, they can use `sys.exit(1)`. Answer updated.